# Infinitesimal Increment of the Wiener Process (squared) - to then prove Ito integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I am a bit stuck trying to compute the infinitesimal increment for $X=W_{t}^{2}$.

I usually would do something like the following but a bit lost..

$x_{t} = W_{t}*W_{t}$

$x_{t+h} = (W_{t+h}-W_{t}) (W_{t+h}-W_{t})$

$x_{t+h} = (W_{t+h}^2)-2*(W_{t+h}W_{t})-(W_{t}^2)$

But I am sure this is not correct somewhere as I can't find any simplification to use in the second part....

I need to use the solution here to proof the Ito Integral for

$ \int_{0}^{u} W_{t}dW{t} = \frac{1}{2}(W_{u}^{2}-U)$

Any pointers/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The increment of $x_t=W_t^2$ is *not* your expression for $x_{t+h}\,$.

It is
\begin{align}
x_{t+h}-x_t&=W_{t+h}^2-W_t^2=W_{t+h}^2-2W_{t+h}W_t+W_t^2-2W_t^2+2W_{t+h}W_t\\
&=(W_{t+h}-W_t)^2+2W_t(W_{t+h}-W_t).
\end{align}
By the definition of the Ito integral and the quadratic variation this implies
$$
x_t=W_t^2=\langle W\rangle_t+2\int_0^tW_s\,dW_s=t+2\int_0^tW_s\,dW_s
$$
which is equivalent to the equation you wanted to prove.

Comment: Thank you! It certainly helped. May I ask why the 2+ℎ terms do not cancel out?

Comment: I do not see a $2W_t+hW_t$ term.

Comment: My mistake, I did not have my lenses in. I follow. Thank you!